# Why not circle retain when dismiss view controller (non-arc)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this code in non-arc, and I think it has a problem - circle retain (**self (UIViewController) has the ownership of complete-block, complete-block has the ownership of self**). But when I debug, it run in dealloc (mean that not have circle retain count as I think)

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self goToChatViewController:buddyEntity];
}];
```

Can someone explain for me, why it not circle retain in this code?

Comment: Using self inside a block will *sometimes* create a retain cycle. 99% of the time it will not create a retain cycle and is perfectly safe. The key is knowing when it's an issue... for which there is plenty of documentation available. Stack Overflow is not the place to explain that. Without seeing more of your code, I can't tell you if you have a retain cycle or not.

Comment: I think above code is enough for this question. I think in my mind, self hold completion-block, completion-block hold self. But I don't know "what wrong in my mind", why it not circle retain. Why you say "99% of the time it will not create a retain cycle". I think it is 100% circle retain, but it not correct

Comment: What makes you think the code above will create a retain cycle?

Comment: Because I think "self hold completion-block, completion-block hold self"

Comment: Since you're not using ARC nothing holds onto anything.

Comment: In this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710710/objective-c-memory-management-with-blocks-arc-and-non-arc), someone say "In both ARC and non-ARC enabled environments, "self" will be retained according to this article from Apple". I don't know who is right (you or him). Can you give me a document link, say that "not using ARC nothing holds onto anything"

Comment: That question is all about instance variables. You don't have any instance variable. As I said, 99% of the time there is no retain cycles. Instance variables are among the 1%.

Comment: Thank you, may be that "Since you're not using ARC nothing holds onto anything" is my mistake. I think non-arc also retain object in block. But can you give me a document about that?

Comment: Even if you are using ARC, blocks usually don't create retain cycles. There are only some situations where it is an issue. See @JamesSnook's answer for an explanation of why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't hold reference at this block. So this block deallocated after completion.
When block deallocating it release object that it hold.
So there is all ok. You can courageously use `self` inside such blocks.

Retain cycles appear for example if you use block as property or add it in container.

Comment: In code below SDK, I think UIViewController have to save completion-block as a property, to call it after dismiss complete. But it is not retain circle. If they don't store completion-block, how it can call block when dismiss complete ?

Comment: @huync, `UIViewController` will copy block, but it will release it after calling.

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer make me understand. Accepted

Answer (score 0):

A block is secretly an ObjectiveC object. When you create a block in the background objectiveC creates an instance of a block class (although quite weirdly it creates it on the stack rather than the heap, unless you copy the block). The objects used inside of your block become instance variables of the block object.

Because the block object is on the heap, not on the stack normally when you get to the end of the method you are in the block object falls out of scope and everything is great. However if your class calls copy on the block, and keeps a reference, the block is copied to the heap. Now your class has a reference to the block and the block has a reference to your class and you have a retain cycle.

Comment: Every block retain objects that it use. It doesn't matter copy block or not.

Comment: Blocks on the heap don't increment the retain counts of their instance variables. As they are on the heap they don't need to! This happens when you call `copy` on them. At this point they become a slightly different type of object (you will notice this in your debugger if you call `class` on the block object that has been copied) and are move to the heap. After a quick scan this looks like a reasonable explanation of blocks http://albertodebortoli.github.io/blog/2013/04/21/objective-c-blocks-under-the-hood/

Comment: Are you sure? You can create pointer at block. Then release all objects that used in that block. Then call this block from pointer. And look we didn't create block's copy, we used block, located at heap. But all works fine, because block retained objects.

Comment: Shockingly I just wrote the code you suggested and guess what? It crashed http://www.twistedape.me.uk/blog/images/blockCrash.png don't forget to turn zombies if you want to copy it.

Comment: You have `EXC_BREAKPOINT` exception. It's not `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Something wrong with you project. My output: `2014-11-25 14:50:18.443 GGTest[2732:303] <NSView: 0x100129cd0>, retainCount = 1`

Comment: Here's the error:

2014-11-25 12:05:34.541 test[632:39942] *** -[NSView retainCount]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x11ec4bf60

You can see all the code in my project.

Comment: @Cy-4AH Of course if I turn off Zombies I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I also don't get the information telling me what the problem was (i.e. sending message to deallocated instance)

Comment: I think we have found bug in Xcode. Same code in ARC works fine, even if I use `__weak` block:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65604/discussion-between-james-snook-and-cy-4ah).